# Validation function for numeric field

Tags: php

I am finishing up this website and working on the last couple validations. 
How can I make the validation for a name field only accept letters and not numbers. And how can i validate a zip code field to contain exactly 5 digits.
Below is what I have so far.

```
//First Name
function check_fname($fname){
if($fname==''){
    return 'Please Enter your First Name.';
}}

//Zip Code
function check_zip($zip){
if(! is_numeric($zip)){
    return 'Please Enter your Zip.';
}}
```

Comment: Validate functions should ONLY return BOOLEAN values. You are on the wrong track. This should be similar to this `if ( ! is_zip_valid($zip) ){ /* add error message to container */ }`

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions:

```
if (preg_match('/^[a-z]+$/i', $fname)) ... // At least one letter

if (preg_match('/^\d{5}$/', $zip)) ... // 5 digits
```

For the name, depending on your demographic you might want to allow foreign characters I recommend this solution which is more forgiving:

```
if (strlen($fname) > 0 && ! preg_match('/\d/', $fname)) ...
```

Comment: if you talk about foreign chars, then `mb_strlen($string, 'UTF-8')` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

For any Unicode (international) letters

```
if (preg_match('/^\pL+$/u', $fname)) ...
```